# Changing href depending on javascript

Tags: javascript, href, setattribute, createelement

I'm trying to figure out the best way to determine the `href` depending on whether javascript is enabled. If javascript is enabled I'd like the `href="#"'

```
<ul>
    <li onclick="openLandscape()"><a class="small-caps bold icon-tree" href="#"><span class="sticky">Landscaping</span></a></li>
    <li onclick="openEdible()"><a class="small-caps bold icon-apple" href="#"><span class="sticky">Edible Accents</span></a></li>
    <li onclick="openPests()">8<a class="small-caps bold icon-android" href="#"><span class="sticky">Pests</span></a></li>
    <li onclick="openProducts()"><a class="small-caps bold icon-shopping-cart" href="#"><span class="sticky">Products</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

If javascript is not enabled I'd like the href to be like below:

```
<ul>
    <li onclick="openLandscape()"><a class="small-caps bold icon-tree" href="#landscaping"><span class="sticky">Landscaping</span></a></li>
    <li onclick="openEdible()"><a class="small-caps bold icon-apple" href="#edible"><span class="sticky">Edible Accents</span></a></li>
    <li onclick="openPests()">8<a class="small-caps bold icon-android" href="#pests"><span class="sticky">Pests</span></a></li>
    <li onclick="openProducts()"><a class="small-caps bold icon-shopping-cart" href="#products"><span class="sticky">Products</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Ideas would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Really easy, you could do something like:

```html
<script>
  (function(d){
    d.write("<ul>");
    d.write("<li onclick=\"openLandscape()\"><a class=\"small-caps bold icon-tree\" href=\"#\"><span class=\"sticky\">Landscaping</span></a></li>");
    d.write("<li onclick=\"openEdible()\"><a class=\"small-caps bold icon-apple\" href=\"#\"><span class=\"sticky\">Edible Accents</span></a></li>");
    d.write("<li onclick=\"openPests()\"><a class=\"small-caps bold icon-android\" href=\"#\"><span class=\"sticky\">Pests</span></a></li>");
    d.write("<li onclick=\"openProducts()\"><a class=\"small-caps bold icon-shopping-cart\" href=\"#\"><span class=\"sticky\">Products</span></a></li>");
    d.write("</ul>");
  })(window.document);
</script>

<noscript>
<ul>
    <li onclick="openLandscape()"><a class="small-caps bold icon-tree" href="#landscaping"><span class="sticky">Landscaping</span></a></li>
    <li onclick="openEdible()"><a class="small-caps bold icon-apple" href="#edible"><span class="sticky">Edible Accents</span></a></li>
    <li onclick="openPests()"><a class="small-caps bold icon-android" href="#pests"><span class="sticky">Pests</span></a></li>
    <li onclick="openProducts()"><a class="small-caps bold icon-shopping-cart" href="#products"><span class="sticky">Products</span></a></li>
</ul>
</noscript>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to use javascript to update the href dynamically.

Here is the code

```
<ul>
    <li onclick="openLandscape()"><a class="small-caps bold icon-tree" href="#landscaping"><span class="sticky">Landscaping</span></a></li>
    <li onclick="openEdible()"><a class="small-caps bold icon-apple" href="#edible"><span class="sticky">Edible Accents</span></a></li>
    <li onclick="openPests()">8<a class="small-caps bold icon-android" href="#pests"><span class="sticky">Pests</span></a></li>
    <li onclick="openProducts()"><a class="small-caps bold icon-shopping-cart" href="#products"><span class="sticky">Products</span></a></li>
</ul>

//this script will run only if javascript is enabled
<script>
    //iterate over all the li elements
    var liArray=document.document.querySelectorAll("#sliderMenu li");
    for(var i=0;i<liArray.length;i++){
        var li=liArray[i];
        //set the href of all to #
        li.setAttribute('href',"#");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I've got other lists on the page. If I add `<ul id="sliderMenu">` how do I edit the javascript to pick  up just that group?

Comment: what you can is to use document.querySelectorAll("#sliderMenu li") instead of getElementByTagName('li'). I have updated my solution as well